# Opensearch Connector for SharePoint 2013 Foundation not returning any results

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint, search

I want to connect the SharePoint search to the local windows 7 search via an opensearch connector.
But when I search for something it always return no results but the search on wbsite link works.
The contents of my .osdx file are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:ms-ose="http://schemas.microsoft.com/opensearchext/2009/"> 
<ShortName>SharePoint Search</ShortName> 
<Description>Search the SharePoint site.</Description> 
<Url type="application/rss+xml" template="http://host/sites/mysite/search/_layouts/15/srchrss.aspx?k={searchTerms}"/>
<Url type="text/html" template="http://host/sites/mysite/search/results.aspx?k={searchTerms}"/> 
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

The Links both work correctly when entered into a browser but i noticed that the rss link if entered into chrome does not return results on first try but if I reload the page it does.

What could cause this behaviour ?
I would be grateful for any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that I had enabled anonymous authentication so the first request would be send without an auth token